# Design and Simulation Software for Logic Gates and Discretes

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, logic-gates

I do not have a deep knowledge about Electronics, but I gained my basic knowledge from high-school and self taught after that. I need to know which software I can use to design electronic circuits with logic gates. Basically, I need to design a logic gate system (for a specific purpose) and convert that into a real circuit diagram adding electronic parts (transistors, IC, Resistors etc.) and do the simulation to see whether it works. After that I can assemble the real circuit. Is there any simple software that I can use for this? Any suggestion would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: The first thing to realize is that there's hardly any reason to do what you are describing today outside of an educational environment, and when you do it there, working it out by hand is part of the learning process.  Typically any real system of the complexity of needing several distinct ICs would use the cheapest MCU or a custom function part.  The systems which do need to be fast enough to use a direct logic implementation are too fast for simple board-level interconnect - that logic ends up buried inside an FPGA or ASIC.  If you just want to play with gates, breadboard some DIPs.

Comment: I think you can find here answer for any purpose e.g. [Designing Embedded Software](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/36773/27928), [Circuit analysis - software?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/44736/27928), [Circuit Simulation Software](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/7022/27928) or [digging deeper](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=software)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a program such as LTSpice.  There are also sites that simulate circuits like http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ and https://www.circuitlab.com/.

Comment: @ SolveEtCoagula07. Thanks a lot! this really helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SPICE simulator, for example [LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/solutions/ltspice) which is nice and free. These are more geared towards analog simulation, a bit awkward to use with logic, but it'll work.

For complex logic you can also use something like Xilinx ISE in schematic mode (also free). It's a FPGA design tool, but you don't have to use the FPGA bits, you can just use the logic simulator.

Comment: I forgot about my favorite, spectrum soft Microcap, it is expensive but it has an evaluation version, if your circuit is small enough to work with the free version, you should consider it, the GUI is awesome and it's a pleasure to use.